# How can we saving TableViewCell values into next listView of an TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I just wanna know that how from an ViewController having the **TableViewCells** to be saved to next **TableViewCell** of TableViewController to see as listView. here below I have posted an image of what I have asked. here I have seen so many questions regarding this but none of them matches to my expectation.if any one could help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Table view cells are driven by the data model, this is the array which is mentioned in  the data source methods. You have to get the data from there. And if you have UI elements which modify the data model you have to add logic to update it accordingly. *Saving TableViewCells* to pass data is the wrong approach.

Comment: What you can improve anyway is the handling of the subviews in the cells. Removing the labels and adding them again in `cellForRow` is pretty cumbersome. The most efficient way is to design the cells in the storyboard. If you don't want that assign tags to the labels and add only those which don't exist.